# Setting Design Time Size for Custom Control

Tags: c#, wpf, visual-studio-2010

How do you set the Design Time Width and Height of a custom control?
I have created a custom ItemsControl, i.e. (contents of generic.xaml)

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type MyItemsControl}"   >
    <Setter Property="Height" Value="24" />
    <Setter Property="Width" Value="160" />
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type local:MyItemsControl}" >
                <Grid>
                  ...
                </Grid>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>     
  ...
</Style>
```

And it works all nicely and all, however if I drag the control from the ToolBox onto my window the default size of my control is: Height = 100 and Width = 200. How do I set the design time size so that when I drag the control from the Toolbox to window the default size is 24 and 160 respectively?

Answer (score 0):

May b it helps u..........

> for that firstly u have to make ur own controls by inheriting it with
>   original controls and set Hieght,width and whatever you want in your
>   custom control .........after this when u drag ur own made control
>   form toolbox to ur form it will set by ur way whatever u wanted.......

Answer (score 0):

This is a setting within Visual Studio itself, and there doesn't seem to be a way to change it, nor is Microsoft planning on changing it.

Source: [A user reported this issue to Microsoft online and a Microsoft employee responded and marked the issue as "Won't Fix".](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/62538/wpf-usercontrol-height-always-set-to-100.html)